# What would be a good way to understand (A x A) - (B x C) = (A - B) x (A - C)?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm studying Cartesian Products and am tasked with proving or disproving (A x A) - (B x C) = (A-B)x(A-C). However, I'm having difficulties understanding what, exactly, is being stated, and hence that prevents me from starting any type of proof. I think that what looms over my lack of understanding in this is how to work with the Cartesian product *and* the complement set, especially how those two concepts overlap in the problem. Could someone please provide some clarity?

Comment: Hint: When are two sets equal?

Comment: Draw pictures would work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Take it one step at a time .  It may also help to use $\neg~z\in Z$ rather than $z\notin Z$.

$\begin{align}&\qquad(A\times A)\smallsetminus(B\times C)\\&=\{\langle x,y\rangle: (\langle x,y\rangle\in A\times A)\wedge\neg(\langle x,y\rangle\in B\times C)\}&&\text{def'n of set difference}\\&=\{\langle x,y\rangle: (x\in A\wedge y\in A)\wedge\neg(x\in B\wedge y\in C)\}&&\text{def'n of cartesian product}\\&=\{\langle x,y\rangle: (x\in A\wedge y\in A)\wedge(\neg~x\in B\color{red}\vee\neg~ y\in C)\}&&\text{deMorgan's Rules}\\[3ex]&\qquad(A\smallsetminus B)\times(A\smallsetminus C)\\&=\{\langle x,y\rangle:(x\in A\smallsetminus B)\wedge (y\in A\smallsetminus C)\}&&\text{def'n cartesian product}\\&=\{\langle x,y\rangle:(x\in A\wedge\neg~ x\in B)\wedge(y\in A\wedge\neg~ y\in C)\}&&\text{def'n set difference}\\&=\{\langle x,y\rangle:(x\in A\wedge y\in A)\wedge(\neg~x\in B\color{red}\wedge\neg~ y\in C)\}&&\text{Commutativity and Association}\end{align}$

As you can plainly see, these set builders do not have equivalent conditions.

You shall then be able to find a counter example which will demonstrate this.

Answer (score 2):

I would propose using one Cartesian product that you definitely know — the coordinate plane — to help you visualize the problem. After all, the usual coordinate plane
$$\mathbb{R}^2=\color{blue}{\mathbb{R}}\times\color{magenta}{\mathbb{R}}=\{(x,y)\mid x\in\color{blue}{\mathbb{R}},y\in\color{magenta}{\mathbb{R}}\}$$
is an example of the Cartesian product of two sets, isn't it?

If $F\subseteq\color{blue}{\mathbb{R}}$ and $G\subseteq\color{magenta}{\mathbb{R}}$ are, for example, intervals on the $x$- and $y$-axes, respectively, then their Cartesian product is a rectangle formed by the intersection of the two stripes. Say, in the example below, $F=[2,6]$ and $G=[3,5]$, and then $F\times G$ is the rectangle in the middle.

[image]     [image]

Now, just as an example, take some interval $A$, for example $A=[1,10]$. Then $A\times A$ is a square. Consider $B=[1,2]$ on the $x$-axis and $C=[1,3]$ on the $y$-axis. And now draw two pictures: what is $(A\times A)-(B\times C)$ and what is $(A-B)\times(A-C)$?

Of course, this is just an example. You still need to learn to work with Cartesian products in general. But I hope that visualizing can help you develop some initial understanding.

Answer (score 1):

The Cartesian product of two sets has an ordered pair between each pair of elements straddling both sets. For example, $\{1,2\}×\{1,2\}=\{(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2)\}$.

The set difference $A-B$ is a subset of $A$; it contains those elements that are in $A$ but not in $B$. For example, $\{1,2,3,4\}-\{2,3,5\}=\{1,4\}$.

Now set $A=\{1,2\},B=C=\{2\}$ and compare both sides of the claim at hand. See what you get.

Answer (score 0):

Consider we can partition $A$ into two distinct parts: All the elements that are also in $B$, and all the elements that are not in $B$.  That is  $A = (A\cap B) \cup (A\setminus B)$.  (And, $(A\cap B)\cap (A\setminus B) =\emptyset$.

Likewise we can partition $A$ into the elements that are in $C$ and the elements that are not in $C$.  That is $A = (A\cap C)\cup (A\setminus C)$.

So that cuts up $A\times A$ into four distinct parts:

$A\times A = [(A\cap B)\cup (A\setminus B)]\times [(A\cap C)\cup (A\setminus C)]=$

1) $[A\cap B]\times [A\cap C] \cup$

2) $[A\cap B]\times [A\setminus C] \cup$

3) $[A\setminus B] \times [A\cap C] \cup$

4) $[A\setminus B]\times [A\setminus C]$

....Now part 1) will be a subset of $B\times C$.  That is $[A\cap B]\times [A\cap C]\subset B\times C$.  But parts 2), 3), and 4) will have no part of $B\times C$.

So $(A\times A)\setminus (B\times C)$ will be parts 2)3) and 4) combined but not 1).

That is $(A\times A)\setminus (B\times C)=[A\cap B]\times [A\setminus C] \cup [A\setminus B] \times [A\cap C] \cup [A\setminus B]\times [A\setminus C]$.

Now $(A\setminus B)\times (A\setminus C)$ is .... simply part 4).  So no, they are not equal

(unless 2) and 3) are empty...)

Answer (score 0):

$A\times B:=\{(a,b):a\in A,b\in B\}$ and $A-B:=\{a\in A:a\notin B\}$ BUT 
the claim $$(A\times A) -(B\times C)=(A-B)\times (A-C)$$ is NOT universally true. One counterexample is the case $A=B=\{1,2\}\;\text{with}\;B\cap C=\emptyset$, say $C=\{3,4\}$, so that the claim becomes 
$$\{1,2\}\times\{1,2\}-\{1,2\}\times\{3,4\}=(\{1,2\}-\{1,2\})\times(\{1,2\}-\{3,4\})$$ 
$$\{1,2\}\times\{1,2\}=\emptyset\times\{1,2\}=\emptyset$$ which is obviously false.